# Unable to read data from a file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read data from a file with a well documented format. I succeed at the first read (getting the first 256 bytes), but fail at the second reading.

Prior to the second `inputFile.Read()` the parameters are:

> File length: 2263778
>
> `bytes2` Array length: 768
>
> `Me.BytesInHeaderRecord - staticHeaderSize` Bytes to read: 768
>
> `staticHeaderSize` Offset (starting point): 256

```
   Public Sub New(filePath As String)
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim inputFile = IO.File.Open(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = New Byte(staticHeaderSize - 1) {} 
        inputFile.Read(bytes, 0, staticHeaderSize) ' <-- This works
        CreateStaticHeader(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes))

        Dim bytes2 = New Byte(CInt(Me.BytesInHeaderRecord - staticHeaderSize - 1)) {}
        Dim newLength = CInt(Me.BytesInHeaderRecord - staticHeaderSize)
        'Debug.Print("Filelength: " & CType(inputFile.Length, String))
        'Debug.Print("Array length: " & CType(bytes2.Length, String))
        'Debug.Print("Bytes to read: " & CType(newLength, String))
        'Debug.Print("Offset (starting point): " & CInt(staticHeaderSize))
        inputFile.Read(bytes2, CInt(staticHeaderSize), bytes2.Length) '<-- This does not work
        'Debug.Print("read data: " & System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2))
        CreateSignalHeaders(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2))

        inputFile.Close()
    End Sub
```

`CreateStaticHeader` and `CreateSignalHeaders` are two private sub-routines to fill the class fields - one of which is `Me.BytesinHeaderRecord`.

However, when I run the code, I get an exception at the second time that I try to read data:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> Message=Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is
>   greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the
>   source collection.
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

The help from the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8) (C# instead of VB.Net but still the .Net framework)

> **Read**(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
>
> Reads a block of bytes from the stream and writes the data in a given
>   buffer.
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> **array**
>
> Byte[]
>
> When this method returns, contains the specified byte array with the
>   values between offset and (offset + count - 1) replaced by the bytes
>   read from the current source.
>
> **offset**
>
> Int32
>
> The byte offset in array at which the read bytes will be placed.
>
> **count**
>
> Int32
>
> The maximum number of bytes to read.

As far as I can see, I am calling the right code.

### Edit

The numbers used are confirmed through the debug code provided.

```
        'Debug.Print("Filelength: " & CType(inputFile.Length, String))
        'Debug.Print("Array length: " & CType(bytes2.Length, String))
        'Debug.Print("Bytes to read: " & CType(newLength, String))
        'Debug.Print("Offset (starting point): " & CInt(staticHeaderSize))
```

Comment: @downvoter: Please provide some feedback on how you think this question does not show enough research, or how it is unclear, or how it is not useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the help from the MS documentation (link in the OP). The "offset" relates to where the read data is stored in the provided array and in this case, the number of bytes to be read was running past the end of the array.

However, misinterpreting this is understandable because starting a read from an offset in a file is certainly more intuitive than offsetting where the bytes are to be stored in an array that in all the examples for the code is specifically declared for that read. The lesson here is that trusting intuition over carefully reading the documentation is fraught with danger!

> Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
>
> Reads a block of bytes from the stream and writes the data in a given
> buffer.
>
> Byte[]
>
> When this method returns, contains the specified byte array ***with the***
> ***values*** between offset and (offset + count - 1) ***replaced by the bytes
> read*** from the current source.
>
> offset
>
> Int32
>
> The byte offset ***in array*** at which the read bytes will be placed.
>
> count
>
> Int32
>
> The maximum number of bytes to read.

### Edit January 2021

The revised code that does read. The difference is in the second `Read`, which starts from 0, not the offset figure. This is because it is a stream, not a static data block.

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim inputFile As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    ParseFile(inputFile)
    inputFile.Close()
End Sub



Private Sub ParseFile(parsableFile As IO.FileStream)
    Dim header1Bytes() As Byte = New Byte(staticHeaderSize - 1) {}

    'header1Bytes.
    parsableFile.Read(header1Bytes, 0, header1Bytes.Length) ' no error checking here yet!
    CreateStaticHeader(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(header1Bytes))

    Dim header2bytes = New Byte(CInt(Me.BytesInHeaderRecord - staticHeaderSize - 1)) {}
    parsableFile.Read(header2bytes, 0, header2bytes.Length) ' no error checking here yet!
    ' <other code here> 

End Sub
```

Comment: @downvoter. Please provide some feedback on how you think  this answer is not useful. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the code did not do what you expected, but it would also be useful to know what code you used that did read a block of data from a specified starting point in the file.

Comment: @TimMakins: Added a bit, but probably not what you were expecting. In this case, I am reading a stream (or a file turned into a stream), so it is a different concept than a random access file.